Python command in a batch file if statement does not appear to return to script
When I run this batch file with an argument dopy, the code within the if statement runs, but the final two echos never get printed.
@echo off
IF "%1" == "dopy" (
    echo "Dopy mode activated"
    REM run the python file test.py that just has print("hello world")
    python test.py
    echo "python ended"
)
echo "hello again after the if block"

If I run it without the argument, the final two echos get printed.
I expected to see "hello again after the if block", after the if block printed, but I don't see it. If I exclude the python test.py statement, I do see it. If the argument is not dopy, again I see it.

Presumably test.py simply doesn't exit, at least not within the amount of time that you've waited.  We can only guess, since you haven't shown us the actual code.

I cannot reproduce your problem - the posted code worked fine for me. All echos occurred, regardless of whether python existed or not or whether test.py existed or not. Perhaps you have over-cropped your code.

@jasonharper : The python code is print("hello world") - in the REM statement.

Given what you've posted, this statement cannot be correct, "If I run it without the argument, the final two echos get printed". There should only be one echo in such a scenario!

Isn't the python command a .BAT python.bat file? If so, you must call python test.py it...

...however in such a scenario, you should not be creating code which is trusting to luck like this. When you write your code, please use, "P:\athTo\python.ext", where .ext can be .exe, (what everyone assumed), or .bat or .cmd in the current working directory, (which seems to be the case here). You should not be relying on the content of the end users Path environment variables, knowing the current directory at that time, or the content and order of the PathExt variable. Please take time to read through the content of call /?, (in a Command Prompt window), to find out why.

Thank you, and sorry for the delayed reply. The tip to use CALL was already provided to me when the question was in staging ground itself, so I was not checking SO after that. Using Call indeed fixed the problem. Thank you to everyone who answered !!
